# Location search autocomplete that integrates with bing/google geocoding

Tags: jquery, google-maps, autocomplete, geolocation, bing-maps

Any nice suggestions on auto complete location searches, that integrate with something like Google or Bings location data?

I am wanting capture the location of my users on sign up, currently I have a free text input box. I am wanting to have some sort of auto complete that guides the user to inputting more sanitised information, ideally I would like to geo-code the user too.

I'm currently using  the jQuery [autocomplete](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete) for the autosearch, but this requires me to provide the location data, which i dont have or want to maintain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't want to maintain your own database of locations (good for you!), then you might look at Freebase and their [Freebase Suggest](http://www.freebase.com/docs/suggest) plugin for jQuery.  They'll do all the auto-completion and even the suggestion UI for you and you can specify that you just want to auto-complete locations (or only US counties, or whatever).

There exist gazetteers who can provide the database of location names but won't do the auto-complete UI for you.  [GeoNames](http://www.geonames.org/), for example, has a nice set of [web services](http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html), which you could match up with jQuery Autocomplete.

Comment: Kinda cool, but its very US centric, and the wiki like pop-ups are abit overkill.

Comment: Gazetteers can provide you with a fuller database of names.  (I've updated my answer with some links.)

Comment: Also, if you don't like Freebase Suggest's flyouts, I'd suggest `{"flyout":"false"}`.

Answer (score 2):

We do something similar for the "billing address" field on https://bombsheets.com/ -- you need to do an AJAX call to get the autocomplete options:

```
 $(".address-autocomplete").autocomplete('/get_address', {
   delay: 250,
   scrollHeight: 400,
   matchSubset: false,
   cacheLength: 10,
   minChars: 3
 });
```

And then use a geolocation API server-side to get the actual addresses (we use Rails' excellent [GeoKit](http://geokit.rubyforge.org/)).

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185264/is-an-autocomplete-text-box-for-entering-addresses-a-good-idea) for some additional color.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/lorenzsell/Geocoded-Autocomplete
This jQuery plugin uses Google Geocoding Javascript API and jQuery UI Autocomplete.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <script>
        function init() {
            var input = document.getElementById('locationTextField');
            var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

            ///Start for getting lat and lang

            google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed',
               function() {
                  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
                  var lat = place.geometry.location.lat();
                  var lng = place.geometry.location.lng();
                  document.getElementById("lat").innerHTML = "Lat: "+lat+"<br />Lng: "+lng;
               }
            );

            ////End
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
    </script>
```