# How to make an autocomplete address field with google maps api?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

Using Google Maps API and JQuery I would like to have an Address field that when typing it will autocomplete the address entered there. How this could be achieved?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323661/location-search-autocomplete-that-integrates-with-bing-google-geocoding

Comment: Here is an example (before Google Maps API Autocomplete)
http://gerger.co/blog/2011/02/17/google-maps-api-v3-location-search-with-jquery-autocomplete-plugin/

Comment: This is pretty good: http://gmap3.net/examples/address-lookup.html

Comment: @JohnMagnolia link is not working

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Well, better late than never. Google maps API v3 now provides address autocompletion.

API docs are here: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Autocomplete

A good example is here:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete.html

Comment: be careful using this as entry for a shipping address.
for instance try entering
'11960 iowa avenue #10, los angeles ca'. This address requires an apartment, but their API doesn't know that and in fact won't even let you go to that address. Other addresses I've tried that require an apartment # do work - but there's some in their database that don't work. Great for straight up map, but don't expect a validated address to ship to

Comment: I agree, it is pretty basic and won't suit everybody. But it is very easy to set up and works well.

Comment: You also can't use this on a site behind a login without paying a minimum of $10,000/yr (the bottom price for Google Maps API v3 for Business)

Comment: @ChrisMoschini - I've found conflicting information here: "You are free to use Autocomplete in any application, even if you are not displaying a map. All we ask is that you display the ‘powered by Google’ logo under the text field when you use Autocomplete without a map" [posted 5.1012, googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.co.uk](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/faster-address-entry-with-google-places.html). Perhaps there are limits?

Comment: @orionrush There's not only a lot of conflicting and incomplete info, but it looks like the new Google Places API came with a whole new set of terms, some of which seem to replace old terms, some which leave holes the old terms fill. On top of that Google has inconsistent enforcement, and for free usage, no support - heck they won't even answer a basic question about it. That said we make use of the maps and Places APIs and based on what's been blocked and what hasn't, my above statement remains my best guess.

Comment: I agree with Simon_Weaver and found that google doesn't know about apartments, Post Office Boxes, Private Bags or some rural delivery addresses.  Google is great for pizza delivery or Uber pickups but not so much for postal addresses.  I ended up just using Google Tag Manager (https://www.addy.co.nz/address-finder-gtm-demo) and an address autocomplete API code generator (https://www.addy.co.nz/address-validation-javascript-code-generator) to validate New Zealand addresses for our website.

Comment: Can you customize how many addresses you want to return ?

Comment: @user1532976 no, the API does not specify that as an option

Comment: Ok got it , thought so Thanks

Answer (score 12):

It is easy, but the Google API examples give you detailed explanation with how you can get the map to display the entered location. For only autocomplete feature, you can do something like this.

First, enable Google Places API Web Service. Get the API key. You will have to use it in the script tag in html file.

```
<input type="text" id="location">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[YOUR_KEY_HERE]&libraries=places"></script>
<script src="javascripts/scripts.js"></scripts>
```

Use script file to load the autocomplete class. Your scripts.js file will look something like this.

```
    // scripts.js custom js file
$(document).ready(function () {
   google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
});

function initialize() {
    var input = document.getElementById('location');
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
}
```

Comment: Thank you my friend! helped me a lot.

Answer (score 6):

Below I split all the details of formatted address like City, State, Country and Zip code.

So when you start typing your street name and select any option then street name write over street field, city name write over city field and all other fields like state, country and zip code will fill automatically.

### Using Google APIs.

```
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {
    var places = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document
            .getElementById('txtPlaces'));
    google.maps.event.addListener(places, 'place_changed', function() {
        var place = places.getPlace();
        var address = place.formatted_address;
        var  value = address.split(",");
        count=value.length;
        country=value[count-1];
        state=value[count-2];
        city=value[count-3];
        var z=state.split(" ");
        document.getElementById("selCountry").text = country;
        var i =z.length;
        document.getElementById("pstate").value = z[1];
        if(i>2)
        document.getElementById("pzcode").value = z[2];
        document.getElementById("pCity").value = city;
        var latitude = place.geometry.location.lat();
        var longitude = place.geometry.location.lng();
        var mesg = address;
        document.getElementById("txtPlaces").value = mesg;
        var lati = latitude;
        document.getElementById("plati").value = lati;
        var longi = longitude;
        document.getElementById("plongi").value = longi;            
    });
});
```

Comment: +1 I used a variation of this and it works. Just note that when you split 'pstate' to get get the zip code, UK and other countries have spaces in the zip codes so additional modification may be needed there.

Answer (score 6):

Like others have mentioned, the [Google Places Autocomplete API is missing some important functions](https://smartystreets.com/articles/autocomplete#google-places-autocomplete-api). Case in point, Google will not validate that the street number is real, and they also will not put it into a standardized format. So, it is the user's responsibility to enter that portion of the address correctly.

Google also won't predict PO Boxes or apartment numbers. So, if you are using their API for shipping, address cleansing or data governance, you may want one that will validate the building number, autocomplete the unit number and standardize the information.

Full Disclosure, I work for [SmartyStreets](https://smartystreets.com)

Answer (score 5):

Drifting a bit, but it would be relatively easy to autofill the US City/State or CA City/Provence when the user enters her postal code using a lookup table.

Here's how you could do it if you could force people to bend to your will:

1. **User enters:** postal (zip) code

   **You fill:** state, city (province, for Canada)
2. **User starts to enter:** streetname

   **You:** autofill
3. **You display:** a range of allowed address numbers

   **User:** enters the number

Done.

Here's how it is natural for people to do it:

1. **User enters:** address number

   **You:** do nothing
2. **User starts to enter:** street name

   **You:** autofill, drawing from a massive list of every street in the country
3. **User enters:** city

   **You:** autofill
4. **User enters:** state/provence

   **You:** is it worth autofilling a few chars?
5. **You:** autofill postal (zip) code, if you can (because some codes straddle cities).

---

Now you know why people charge $$$ to do this. :)

For the street address, consider there are two parts: numeric and streetname. If you have the zip code, then you can narrow down the available streets, but most people enter the numeric part first, which is backwa

Answer (score 2):

I really doubt it--google maps API is great for geocoding known addresses, but it generally return data that is suitable for autocomplete-style operations. Nevermind the challenge of not hitting the API in such a way as to eat up your geocoding query limit very quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Youtube video reference: https://youtu.be/WxH0J4wOnZA

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="myAddress" placeholder="Enter your address" value="333 Alberta Place, Prince Rupert, BC, Canada" id="myAddress"/>
```

**Google Autofill address**

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places&key=[YOUR-KEY]"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
    var searchInput = 'myAddress';
    
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var autocomplete;
            autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete((document.getElementById(searchInput)), {
                types: ['geocode']
               
            });
        
            google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
                var near_place = autocomplete.getPlace();
            });
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some awesome libraries such as select2, but it doesn't match my need.
I've made a sample from scratch in order to use a simple input text.

I only use bootstrap and JQuery, Hope it'll be useful: [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/yacmed/yp0xmdf5/)

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
    <label for="address">Address</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label for="number">number</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="number">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <label for="street">street</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="street">
    </div>  
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label for="zip">zip</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="zip">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <label for="town">town</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="town">
    </div>  
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label for="department">Department</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="department">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label for="region">Region</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="region">
    </div>  
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label for="country">Country</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="country">
    </div>  
</div>
```

JS:

```
$("input#address").suggest({
    label : "Adresse complete", 
    street_number_input : {
        id : "number",
        label : "Numero de la rue"
    },
    street_name_input : {
        id : "street",
        label : "Nom de la rue"
    },
    zip_input : {
        id : "zip",
        label : "Code postal"
    },
    town_input : {
        id : "town",
        label : "Ville"
    },
    department_input : {
        id : "department",
        label : "Departement"
    },
    region_input : {
        id : "region",
        label : "Region"
    },
    country_input : {
        id : "country",
        label : "Pays"
    }
});
```