# Geocoder v3 Autocomplete Hotel

Tags: autocomplete, geocode

We are running a website (www.taxileader.net/taxi-tegel.html) , where people can book a taxi from the airport to their destination.

To book and calculate the distance between the starting address that normally is an Airport (latitude/longitude already in our database) and their destination we use google map v3

In the "destination field" we already have an autocomplete to extract the zip (or postcode)  from the address our customers are writing in,  BUT we need them to find as well the hotel's zip.

The API call we use to take the address information is geocoder v3, is this wrong or is there something else we have to put to find hotels?

```
$("#txt_indirizzo").autocomplete({
    //This bit uses the geocoder to fetch address values
    source : function(request, response) {
        geocoder.geocode({
            'address' : request.term,
            'bounds' : bound
        }, function(results, status) {
            response($.map(results, function(item) {
                var zip = '';
                for (var i in item.address_components) {
                    if (item.address_components[i].types[0] == 'postal_code' || item.address_components[i].types[1] == 'postal_code') {
                        zip = item.address_components[i].long_name;
                    }
                }
                if (zip == '') {
                    return;
                } else {
                    return {
                        value : item.formatted_address,
                        latitude : item.geometry.location.lat(),
                        longitude : item.geometry.location.lng(),
                        zip : zip
                    }
                }

            }));
        })
    },
    //This bit is executed upon selection of an address
    select : function(event, ui){
        if (tipoDiTrasf == 2) {
            return;
        }

        chk_txt_indirizzo = true;
        if (ui.item.zip != '') {

            chkPostcode(ui.item.zip, ui.item.latitude, ui.item.longitude, ui.item.value, '#txt_indirizzo');

        } else {
            alert('Questo non è un indirizzo valido');
            setTimeout('$("#txt_indirizzo").val("")', 5);
        }
        tab(1);
    },
    change : function() {
        if (!chk_txt_indirizzo) {
            $("#txt_indirizzo").val('').data("autocomplete").term = "";
            zip_indirizzo = pointLat2 = pointLon2 = setIndirizzo = false;
            putondinNam();

        }
    }
});
```

At least is there a way to have the google maps autocomplete to cities only?

I mean in the "cities field" we want to show only cities and not addresses

Many thanks

Comment: We already use geocode to take the zip from the address written by the customer, but in the destination field we need to show with the google autocomplete an hotel list and take the zip from it, just to make an internal calculation.

Comment: I advice you to put it into the question. And not only this phrase. You have to work at the question. A question here should show what have you tried, what problem do you have *exactly*, what have you already done to eliminate it and what were the results. Just now your question looks very undefined. It is only because you are a starter here that it is not closed because of its vagueness. And put tags there. What is your language, for example? There are thousands of them.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, these places could help you?

[Location search autocomplete that integrates with bing/google geocoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323661/location-search-autocomplete-that-integrates-with-bing-google-geocoding)

http://gerger.co/blog/2011/02/17/google-maps-api-v3-location-search-with-jquery-autocomplete-plugin/

http://gmap3.net/en/pages/19-demo/

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer, we already used before one of your links http://gerger.co/blog/2011/02/17/google-maps-api-v3-location-search-with-jquery-autocomplete-plugin/

All of the other links dont show any business place such hotels. 


The geocoder accepts only addresses, we need an API as GETLOCAL (google maps v2 if I remember well) to get business places like hotels